# Loading fonts in twitter bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, sass

I installed bootstrap with SASS (Compass without Rails) and I have some problem:

1. Font url is like this:

   ```
   file:///F:/stylesheets/fonts/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf
   ```

   and page can not find this fonts because url must be like this:

   ```
   file:///F:/SOMETHINGELSE/PROJECT/stylesheets/fonts/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf
   ```

   how can I fix it?
2. How can I build project?
   Main css files is link to gems and I can't understand how can I build project.

Answer (score 0):

By default, Compass sets a path for fonts which may not be correct depending on your directory structure.

http://compass-style.org/help/tutorials/configuration-reference/

You probably need to add something like this to your config.rb:

```
fonts_dir = "path/to/your/fonts"
```